# Checking for Value, if it already exists, dont place it, if it does not exist, place it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have panel-sidebar that has values from all the search panels placed in it. We have a pagination value that, when clicked, is adding values to the panel sidebar whenever it is clicked. I am needing to check for the value in the panel sidebar, if the value exists I dont want to add it again. However, if it is not there, then I need it to be added. Basically, when the pagination is clicked it should not add any further values to the panel sidebar. I am placing the code below, in hopes that someone can help me with this issue. Please let me know if I can further clarify this at all.

```
x = -1;
    lastName = "";
    if( id === "panels-content" ) {
        $("#panels-region .panel-heading").each(function () {
            x++
            console.log($(this))
            let curName = $(this).attr("name")
            if( typeof lastName !== typeof undefined && lastName !== true)
                $('<a id="panels-sidebar-' + curName.replace(
                    / |\//g, "_") + '" class="w3-bar-item" href="#panel-' + x + '-header" title="' + curName.replace(
                    / |\//g, "_") + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ' + curName + '</a>').insertAfter(
                    "#panels-sidebar" + lastName.replace(
                    / |\//g, "_"))
                console.log($(this).attr("name"), lastName)
                lastName = "-" + curName
            }
        })
    }
    $("#graph-region .panel-heading h4").each(function (index) {
        x++
        let curName = $(this).text().replace("Collapse panelExpand panel", "")
        console.log(index)
        if( typeof lastName !== typeof 'undefined' && lastName !== true) {
            $('<a id="tree_viewers-sidebar-' + curName.replace(
                / |\//g, "_") + '" class="w3-bar-item" href="#panel-' + x + '-header" title="' + curName.replace(
                    / |\//g, "_") + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ' + curName + '</a>').insertAfter(
                        "#tree_viewers-sidebar" + lastName.replace(
                            / |\//g, "_"))
            lastName = "-" + curName

            return;

        }
    });
    $(".menu-links a").css("padding", "0px 8px")
    $(".panel-body").css("background-color", "white")
    $("#panels-region .panel-wrapper .panel-default").css("background-color", "white")
}
```

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to revise it, or make it better? I am open to suggestions.

Comment: I would go with a more Object oriented design altogether. Yet, I digress. `typeof 'undefined'` would be `'string'`. Usually you do like `if(typeof lastName !== 'undefined')`, if the variable is not set at all. In your case `lastName = ''`, so it's an empty String. If you set the variable you can just do like `if(lastName !== undefined)`, but you want to test `if(lastName !== '')`. Looks like `lastName !== true` is always true, since you never made it `true`. Side note: Objects that are defined which have undefined properties are okay to test like `if(obj.prop === undefined)`. Just comments.